# How to resolved Shopee API v1 add item error value unit

Tags: php

I have problem in my code

Try add new item with shopee API v1

> spex error : global_attr_id=100061 is customizable NON_quantitative_attribute: invalid field|field_name=item_attr_value_ext_info.customised_value|err=value does not match input validator of global attr|value=2021-07-15|input_validator=VALIDATOR_DATE|: item.attribute.set_item_attr_list failed  attribute [101029] value unit should be in ML, L, MG, G/GR, KG, CM, M, Dozen, Piece, Pack, Set, Box"

this error because attribute unit not match.

how to resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

change your formatting attribute value or key with valid format from VALIDATOR_DATE SHOPEE

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30853906)